# NestJs - Jest - Testing: ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found

Tags: testing, jestjs, tdd, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to write a test of a simple TODO App.

This is my service test class:

```js
    const mockTaskRepository = () => ({
        createTask: jest.fn(),
    });

    describe('TasksService', () => {
        let tasksService;
        let taskRepository;

      beforeEach(async () => {
            const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
                providers: [TasksService, { provide: TaskRepository, useFactory: mockTaskRepository }],
            }).compile();

            tasksService = await module.get<TasksService>(TasksService);
            taskRepository = await module.get<TaskRepository>(TaskRepository);
        });

      describe('create task', () => {
            it('calls taskRepository.create() and returns the result', async () => {
                const createTaskDto = {
                    title: 'Test task',
                    description: 'Test desc',
                };
                taskRepository.createTask.mockResolvedValue('someTask');
                expect(taskRepository.createTask).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
                const result = await tasksService.createTask(createTaskDto);
                expect(taskRepository.createTask).toHaveBeenCalledWith(createTaskDto);
                expect(result).toEqual('someValue');
            });
        });
    });
```

And this is my task service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(TaskRepository)
        private taskRepository: TaskRepository,
    ) {}

    async createTask(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Promise<Task> {
        const { title, description } = createTaskDto;
        const task = new Task();
        task.title = title;

        task.description = description;
        task.status = TaskStatus.IN_PROGRESS;
        await task.save();

        return task;
    }
}
```

When I try to run the Create a Task test, the error below occurs.

```sh
FAIL  src/tasks/tasks.service.spec.ts
  ● TasksService › create task › calls taskRepository.create() and returns the result

    ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

      at new ConnectionNotFoundError (error/ConnectionNotFoundError.ts:8:9)
      at ConnectionManager.Object.<anonymous>.ConnectionManager.get (connection/ConnectionManager.ts:40:19)
      at Object.getConnection (index.ts:247:35)
      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.BaseEntity.getRepository (repository/BaseEntity.ts:85:72)
      at Task.Object.<anonymous>.BaseEntity.save (repository/BaseEntity.ts:50:42)
      at TasksService.createTask (tasks/tasks.service.ts:35:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tasks/tasks.service.spec.ts:69:38)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 8 passed, 9 total
```

Anyone know what's the mistake in the code?

..........................................

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test expected method `Repository.createTask` to be called, but method `Service.createTask` didn't make that call.

**The fix**: Update the **Service method** to delegate to the **Repository method** the task creation.

```js
// tasks.service.ts

async createTask(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto, user: User): Promise<Task> {
        return this.taskRepository.createTask(createTaskDto, user);
}
```

```js
// tasks.repository.ts

async createTask(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto, user: User): Promise<Task> {
        const { title, description } = createTaskDto;
        const task = new Task();
        task.title = title;
        task.user = user;
        task.description = description;
        task.status = TaskStatus.IN_PROGRESS;
        await task.save();
        delete task.user;

        return task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is looking for connection `default` then I assume that the TypeOrmModule configs are still being taken into account. Instead of `provide: TaskRepository` try changing it to `provide: getRepositoryToken(TaskEntity)` if you have a TaskEntity. This will tell Nest to override the default repo that the `@InjectRepository()` decorator tries to provide.

If that isn't the case, do you think you could add your `TaskService` and `TaskModule` classes as well?

Comment: This change didn't work. The error persisted.

As you requested, I updated the description with TaskModule and TaskService.

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the repository then bringing up the context of Test Module. Otherwise, the real Repository is being injected (via Nest's DI) into service.

```
            const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
                providers: [
                {
                      provide: getRepositoryToken(YourEntityClass),
                      useValue: mockedRepo, // or use class
                }, 
                TasksService],
            }).compile();

            tasksService = await module.get<TasksService>(TasksService);
            // taskRepository = await module.get<TaskRepository>(TaskRepository); don't have to do that if `useValue` was used instead of factory
```

So, TL;DR :
`provide: TaskRepository` should provide `Token` of given Injectable in this case: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#non-class-based-provider-tokens